# I cannot save rows to the DB with SQLAchemy + Pyramid

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyramid

After hours of debugging, and because my organization does not have a lot of Python expertise, I am turning to this community for help.

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/quick_tutorial/databases.html) with the goal of committing some data to the database. Although no errors get reported, I am also not saving any rows. What am I doing wrong?

When trying to commit using the db2Session, I get:

Transaction must be committed using the transaction manager.

But nowhere in the tutorial, do I see the transaction manager being used. I thought that this manager is bound using zope.sqlalchemy? Yet, nothing is happening otherwise. Help again would be really appreciated!

I have the following setup in my main function in a Pyramid App:

```
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from .models import db1Session, db2Session

def main(global_config, **settings):
""" This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
"""
    db1_engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'db1.')
    db2_engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'db2.')

    db1Session.configure(bind=db1_engine)
    db2Session.configure(bind=db2_engine)
```

In .models/__init__py, I have:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import (scoped_session, sessionmaker)
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension

db1Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(
    extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
db2Session =      
    scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))

Base = declarative_base()
```

In ./model/db2.py I have:

```
class PlateWellResult(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'SomeTable'
    __table_args__ = {"schema": 'some_schema'}

    id = Column("ID", Integer, primary_key=True)
    plate_id = Column("PlateID", Integer)
    hit_group_id = Column("HitID", Integer, ForeignKey(
        'some_schema.HitGroupID.ID'))
    well_loc = Column("WellLocation", String)
```

The relevant bits of my saving function look like this. ./lib/db2_api.py:

```
def save_selected_rows(input_data, selected_rows, hit_group_id):
    """ Wrapper method for saving selected rows """
    # Assume I have all the right data below.
    new_hit_row = PlateWellResult(
        plate_id=master_plate_id,
        hit_group_id=hit_group_id,
        well_loc=selected_df_row.masterWellLocation)

    db1Session.add(new_hit_row)
    # When I try the row below:
    # db2Session.commit()
    # I get: Transaction must be committed using the transaction manager
    # If I cancel the line above, nothing gets committed.
    return 'Save successful.'
```

That function is called from my viewer:

```
@view_config(route_name='some_routename', renderer='json',
             permission='create_hit_group')
def save_to_hitgroup(self):
    """ Backend to AJAX call to save selected rows to a hit_group """
    try:
        # Assume that all values were checked and all the right 
        # parameters are passed
        status = save_selected_rows(some_result, 
                                    selected_rows_list,
                                    hitgroup_id)
        json_resp = json.dumps({'errors': [],
                                'status': status})
        return json_resp
    except Exception as e:
        json_resp = json.dumps({'errors': ['Error during saving. {'
                                           '0}'.format(e)],
                                'status': []})
        return json_resp
```

Comment: If you search the page you linked for "transaction", there's a line that uses the transaction manager: `with transaction.manager:`. Personally, I avoid such convoluted globals or pseudo-globals. I'm much happier just creating my own `Session` each request.

Comment: Have you used the per request transaction managing package [`pyramid_tm`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tm/en/latest/)? If not, then you're not committing anything. You can also use the transaction manager explicitly as pointed out in the previous post.

Comment: Oh and if you do add it, then remember to manually `transaction.doom()` or `transaction.abort()` in your exception handler as you catch 'em all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above are good. I just wanted to summarize here.

The transaction manager is begun/committed/aborted by pyramid_tm. If you aren't using that then it's likely the issue.

You are also squashing possible database exceptions which need to be conveyed to the transaction manager. You can do this via `transaction.abort()` in the exception handler.